# Adobe Livecycle cacluations and if statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, adobe, rounding, formcollection

my first time posting, and tbh I have very little Xp.  I'm using livecycle for Adobe 9 pro, and trying to make a calculation work, and keep getting error messages.

My basic premise I need to do a calculation:  enter info in cella, and have result of (cella/2)-5 rounded down, keeping the negative integer come out in another cell.  (yes, trying to do my own 3.5 d20 character sheet for ability scores).

In excel I was able to string a slightly more complicated trunc formula of =IF((Cella-10)/2<0,TRUNC((Cella)/2-0.5),TRUNC((Cella-10)/2)), but have no idea what to do in livecycle.

I tried something like this following a tutorial for livecycle, with no avail. honestly noobing it here on all accounts including where notations and variables should be, thanks for the help.

var x = cell1/2-5; if (x <0) {return Math.ceil(x)}; else {return Math.floor(x)}

//cell1 pick from sheet in livecycle using control+click, tried calculation and enter formats on script line.  //Do I need a var x for my formula, not sure, some tutorials said yes, others no for live cycle.  //not sure where to put { }  if at all.  // Math.floor and Math.ceil do not show up highlighted blue like other functions do in the livecycle script bar, which I leave in javamode for all cells.

Comment: Try this:

    `// fieldName::calculate
    var v = this.rawValue/2-5;
    return v<0 ? Math.ceil(v) : Math.floor(v);
    `

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer has got the math right but it won't work in a LiveCycle event (return statement is invalid in an event.)

Let's assume you have two fields: cellA (where you input numbers), cellB (where the rounded result should display). Replace with the actual names in your sheet as necessary.

In the calculate event for cellB (the field that holds the RESULT) put in this code:

```
var v = null;
if (cellA.rawValue != null && cellA.rawValue != "")
{   
    v = cellA.rawValue / 2 - 5; 
    v = v < 0 ? Math.ceil(v) : Math.floor(v);
}
this.rawValue = v;
```

The if statement is there so that it won't calculate when you first open the form.

Side note, the javascript editor in livecycle pretty much sucks so don't expect a lot of help with syntax/formatting.  I would recommend you download Notepad++ and paste the java code in there, it is more helpful for highlighting some syntax and for checking open/closed parentheses.